# Yocto: have a dependency to a receipe and a PACKAGECONFIG

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

Let’s say I have a recipe *foo.bb* containing:

```auto
PACKAGECONFIG[option1] = "..."
PACKAGECONFIG[option2] = "..."
```

Now, I want to write a recipe for package *bar*. In order to run, *bar* requires package *foo* to be compiled with option *option1* but not *option2*.

I know that Yocto is inspired from Gentoo Portage. In portage, this kind of dependency would be written (https://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/dependencies/#built-with-use-dependencies):

```auto
RDEPENDS="foo[option1,-option2]"
```

How can I do the same with Yocto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such mechanism for RDEPENDS in yocto. You can get the same result by:

Putting the foo.bb instructions in an *.inc* file

```
#foo.inc
PACKAGECONFIG[option1] = "..."
PACKAGECONFIG[option2] = "..."
```

Create *foo-option1.bb* and *foo-option2.bb* based on the .inc and the relevant PACKAGECONFIG variable

```
#foo-option1.bb
require foo.inc
PACKAGECONFIG = "option1"


#foo-option2.bb
require foo.inc
PACKAGECONFIG = "option2"
```

Having bar.bb RDEPEND on the correct package

```
#bar.bb
# Can be foo-option2. Up to you
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "foo-option1"
```

The other way is that you add a global variable that you set in a global configuration file, like local.conf or distro.conf and make *foo.bb* use it to enable the option and bar.conf to check if the setting is set and refuse if not. This is fragile in my opinion but is a valid alternative.

There are other ways but I believe this is the easiest from my perspective. If you really want to know other ways let me know, but they are uglier.

PS: Remember that RDEPENDS is used to declare dependencies of packages to runtime **packages**, not recipes. This means that RDEPENDS should always be RDEPENDS_${PN} or the name of the package it is related to.

Comment: This solution doesn't scale with several configuration options.